# Need to add a delimiter in MySQL output from SHELL

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

First off, due to my MySQL user not having FILE rights on the server, I am having to use the below line to pipe my SELECT statement output to a file in shell instead of doing it directly in MySQL and being able to use `INTO OUTFILE` & `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'` which I'm guessing would solve all my problems.

So I have the following line to grab my fields:

```
echo "select id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time), company from database.table_name"  | mysql -h database.mysql.host.com -u username -ppassword  user > /root/sql/output.txt
```

This outputs the following 3 columns:

```
63  1414574321  person one

50  1225271921  Another person

8   1225271921  Company with many names

10  1414574567  Person with Company
```

I then use that data in other scripts to do some tasks.

My issue is that some columns, of which the third here, 'company', is an example, has spaces in its data meaning my WHILE loops later get thrown off.

I would like to add a delimiter to my output so it looks like this instead:

```
63|1414574321|person one

50|1225271921|Another person

8|1225271921|Company with many names

10|1414574567|Person with Company
```

and that way I could hopefully manipulate the data in blocks using `awk -F|` and `IFS=|` later.

There are many many more columns with variable lengths and number of words pr column to be added when I get it working, so I cannot use a method that relies on position to add the delimiter.

I feel the delimiter needs to be set when the data is dumped in the first place.

I've tried things like:

```
echo "select (id, + '|' + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time), + '|' + company) from database.table_name"  | mysql -h database.mysql.host.com -u username -ppassword  user > /root/sql/output.txt
```

without any luck, its just adds the characters to the header of the output file.

Does anyone out there see a solution to what I could do?

In case anyone wonders, I'm dumping data from 2 databases, comparing timestamps and writing back the latest data to both databases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use concat_ws function to recieve one concateneted string per row:

```
select concat_ws( '|', id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) , company ) from database.table_name
```

Edit: Missing comma added, sorry!

Comment: concat_ws give me an error: Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat_ws'

Comment: There was just a missing comma behind the '|'  This works and I am so happy.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Missing comma added above, sorry & glad i could help.